# VLC 'Continue playback' doesn't work until you are quite a bit into the video. It also doesn't remember the playback speed

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-playback

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIK8Y.png)
Playback speed is the speed at which the video is played.

As in the title. I'm using the 3.0.11 version on Windows 10 Pro.
I cannot say how much into the video do I have to be for it to save, because it's  dependant on its lenght.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how "far" into the video you have to be for this to work, how you have tested this and what you mean by "playback speed".